Create a view containing a Slider which updates a generic member
I am pretty new to Swift, and I am trying to achieve something which at first looked pretty simple for me, but I am facing troubles because of concepts of SwiftUI I don't understand.
I have a Bluetooth device which has configurable parameters, and I'd like to create an application to update its configuration. The configuration should be done using sliders. Also, the device should be able to send its configuration to my application and the UI should update accordingly. I've already managed to implement connection and read/write characteristics, so the communication part is ok.
Now, what I am trying to do is to fine the proper way to implement the configuration update (in both way). What I've tried so far is to create a model of the configuration, make it conforming to @Observable protocol and make its fields @Published. So on the UI side, it can be accessed using @Environment (and .environmentObject() when calling the view).
Here is what I've done so far. For the model, I used Generics because parameters can have different types (Float, Int32 etc.)
struct AlgoParam<T> {
    
    var description: String
    var minValue: T
    var maxValue: T
    var step: T
    var defaultValue: T
    var value: T
}

class AlgoParamList: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var baseCurrent_mA: AlgoParam<Float>
    @Published var thresholdAcceleration_mps2: AlgoParam<Float>
    
    init()
    {
        baseCurrent_mA = AlgoParam<Float>(description: "Base current (mA)", minValue: 0, maxValue: 12000, step: 1000, defaultValue: 1000, value: 1000)
        thresholdAcceleration_mps2 = AlgoParam<Float>(description: "Acceleration threshold (mps2)", minValue: -1.0, maxValue: 1.0, step: 0.05, defaultValue: 0.75, value: 0.75)
    }
}

Then, here is the ParameterView (still work in progress, but it's the latest compiling version) containing the Slider and some text such as description of the parameter. For now, the value of the slider is stored in sliderValue, but my goal would be to store it directly to algoParam.value field:
struct ParameterView<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>: View {
    
    var algoParam: AlgoParam<T>
    
    @State private var sliderValue = 5.0
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text(algoParam.description)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            HStack {
                
                VStack {
                    Text(String(format: "%.3f", sliderValue)).font(.title)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)

                }.foregroundColor(isEditing ? .red : .secondary)
                
                VStack {
                    Slider(
                        value: $sliderValue,
                        in: Double(algoParam.minValue)...Double(algoParam.maxValue),
                        step: Double.Stride(algoParam.step),
                        onEditingChanged: { editing in
                            isEditing = editing
                        }
                    )
                }
                
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        print("Click on reset")
                        sliderValue = Double(algoParam.defaultValue)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 20)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear() {
            sliderValue = Double(algoParam.defaultValue)
        }
    }
}

So... Here is the point I've reached for now, but I am feeling stuck, out of ideas, and a bit lost in this very new paradigm to me.
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated :)
